# TODO в NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Есть ли какой то плагин для netbeans или системная функция которая бы при входе в программу напоминала что я собирался сделать, по всем проектам. По типа оповещения по TODO?

Answer (score 1):

В окне 'Элементы действий' автоматически сканируется код и отображаются строки с комментариями, содержащими такие слова, как "TODO" или "FIXME", а также строки с ошибками компиляции, быстрыми исправлениями и предупреждения о стилях.

Это выписка со [страницы](https://netbeans.org/features/ide/index_ru.html).

Comment: Это я в курсе, но если у меня несколько проектов в разных группах, из всех же не отобразится.

Comment: Что Вы называете группами?

Comment: Группами я называю группы проектов ) Есть такая возможность в netbeans объединить проекты в группы

Comment: Не совсем понял. Возможно Вы имели ввиду категории. Я у себя открыл окно, у меня проекты категорий HTML5, PHP, Python, Java - далее в окне есть кнопка "отобразить для всех открытых проектов" (2 иконки проекта друг за другом), и мне отобразилось действительно много строк.

Comment: http://c2n.me/3jn5JoG
т.е. можно отобразить только для открытых проектов. а для других групп нельзя

Comment: Честно говоря не пользовался никогда.